# Is there an RSS feed available for photos/albums posted by Facebook friends?

Tags: facebook, rss, album, photos

There are RSS feeds for friends' Posts, Notes, and Statuses, but there doesn't appear to be one available for Photos/Albums. Does Facebook provide one, or is there another way to get an RSS feed for this?

Comment: I would think so, since Tweetdeck has a column where you can subscribe to new photos posted by your Facebook friends.

Comment: I hope you find your answer here.  I like how you originally asked on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/11801/is-there-an-rss-feed-available-for-photos-albums-posted-by-facebook-friends

Answer (score 1):

There is no publicly available RSS feed. Tweetdeck uses the Graph API to gather all photos from the user and updates the client based on new one received which aren't already in their database.

There IS a nice solution for Facebook Groups implemented using Yahoo Pipes (which seems to be old and no longer works). Possibly it can be modified to work with users. http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=055b7fbcb01605dbd34e5287b8eee8cd

Comment: no it cannot be modified unfortunately, robots.txt disallows this.

Comment: Pipes is still under active development -- I'll check that pipe out, thanks.

Comment: @phwd: What do you mean it can't be modified. I was talking about the Yahoo Pipe I linked and you can clone it and change it however you like.

@arathorn: Pipes has been under "active" development for years. I wouldn't let that deter you from giving it a whirl.

I wrote a few thoughts about the platform's clout back in October 2009 if you're interested in reading. (http://nobulb.com/2009/10/has-yahoo-pipes-reached-its-potential/)

Comment: Sorry for the mixup I meant this part "Possibly it can be modified to work with users. " Been trying it the past week and I either get an error response or robots.txt message when trying to work it for users or albums.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Photo2RSS](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=2422316440) but its reported that it doesn't work always (haven't tried it though).